# Route and block HTTPS requests by domain with privoxy and havp

Tags: networking, openvpn, linux-networking, ufw, privoxy

I'm configuring Privoxy and HAVP to run with OpenVPN and i'm stuck trying to block websites that use HTTPS (not all of them, some of them).

I'm using the following in before.rules of UFW to redirect every request that comes in from the VPN users to HAVP

```
-A PREROUTING -i tun+ -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8080
-A PREROUTING -i tun+ -p tcp --dport 443 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8080
```

and then in HAVP's configuration file i have this:

```
PARENTPROXY 127.0.0.1
PARENTPORT 8118
```

The problem is that the HTTP requests complete successfully and a web page is returned, but the same isn't true for HTTPS.

Am I missing something?

My only goal is not to filter the page in any way, I just want to block the request if the domain is equal to i.e. example.org